# Get secrets from Azure KeyVault to Databricks to use in python Spotify API (spotipy)

Tags: api, spotify, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault

I want to use secrets from KeyVault to authenticate credentials in Spotify API (spotipy).
I set client id and secret key in KeyVault Secrets.
In databricks I have:

```
client_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = 'ClientID', key = 'ClientID')
secret = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = 'SecretKey', key = 'SecretKey')
```

and it works because I get `[REDACTED]` from above variables.
When I use this vars in order to authenticate I get:

```
SpotifyOauthError: error: invalid_client, error_description: Invalid client
```

Keys work fine when I put them straight into Spotify API.
What can be the cause of it? Should I decrypt them somehow before sending to API, but that seems to be senseless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the documentation.

https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.9.0/

Try hard coding the information as plain text in a test call.  If this works, then it is the databricks variable issue.  If it does not work, it is your call to spotify.

[image]

How do you know if the secret in the scope is correct?

You can use this function to verify the information stored in the key vault backed secret scope is correct.  It decodes the secret into text with a space between each character.

For the life of me, I don't know why ret.strip() would get ride of the single spaces.  Something to add to my to-do.

In short, a redacted variable should be able to be passed as a text parameter without issue.

Comment: Wow, your function works xD Now credentials work, but stored secrets was fine (checked by function). I think that I made mistake by passing dbutils keys objects to python module, which has no grant to spark dbutils. When I do it straight from databricks notebook it is OK. Thank you anyway.